# Why am i using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ,TwoWay is not enough?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, propertychanged

hi; there are Source and target textbox txttarget has a binding to txtsource. when writing something in txtsource, txttarget is changed.Everything is good. But writing on txttarget, i dont see any changes at txttarget? there is TwoWay mode. Twoway mode is not enough? can i write without using "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"?

```
   <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,62,0,0" Name="txtSource" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSource,Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 Margin="155,113,0,0" Name="txtTarget" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`txtTarget.Text` is updated whenever the bound source (`txtSource.Text`) changes.

The binding mode is `TwoWay` which means that changes to `txtTarget.Text` will be reflected to the bound source. When? It depends on the `Binding.UpdataSourceTrigger` property.

If you want your target binding to update your source binding when changing you must use 
`Binding.UpdataSourceTrigger = OnPropertyChanged`, otherwise you will update the binding source when txtTarget losts focus (default behavior).

Answer (score 18):

The default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for a `TextBox` is `LostFocus` (see [Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)).  If you do not specify `PropertyChanged` as the UpdateSourceTrigger, what you type into `txtTarget` will not be written to `txtSource` until `txtTarget` loses focus (that is you tab off of it).